# Port this snippet from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have the following code snippet in Matlab and want to port it to Python.

```
for i=1:runs;
   tic;
   datmat=importdata('data.txt',' ');
    Limits_Area=[1,261,522,784,1045,1305,1565,1827,2088,2349,2610,2871,3131,3158];
   for k=1:2000;
      for j=1:13;
         Year_Data=datmat.data(Limits_Area(j):Limits_Area(j+1)-1,4:37);
         Min_Year=min(Year_Data);
         Max_Year=max(Year_Data);
         Mean_Year=mean(Year_Data);
         GainLoss_Year=100-(Year_Data(1,:)+0.00000001)./(Year_Data(end,:)+0.00000001)*100;
     end;
   end;
```

I am having a really hard time with the

`Year_Data=datmat.data(Limits_Area(j):Limits_Area(j+1)-1,4:37);`

part.... Any directions?

Thank you

Comment: It would be nice if you could show some of the data from `data.txt`, and provide some explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, for those of us who know python but aren't fluid in matlab. Can you show us what you tried and how that failed? Additionally, there seems to be a bug in your code in the sense that the outer loop runs the inner loop 2000 times in _exactly_ the same way. Why?

Comment: Hello Roland, the data seems to be a .txt file containing currency values throughout time with columns: KEY Month Day and then a series of three character currency codes ie AUD ATS etc. What I am trying to accomplish is just take this Matlab code and port it into python, no questions asked. I am not fluent in Matlab either, that's why I am trying to understand that specific line. It's actually a silly "benchmarking" code someone wrote, so what you see as a bug... is a actually a feature.

Comment: What's happening in this line is called indexing. You are selecting specific rows and columns in the ´datamat.data´ matrix: rows from Limits_Area(j) to Limits_Area(j+1) and columns 4 to 37. Limits_Area(j) is indexing in a vector and simply means j-th element of Limits_Area. http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html Numpy has a very similar syntax so if it is supposed to look the same in Matlab, use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried numpy ? it is a library for scientific computing which looks like Matlab. For example :

> In Matlab :
> `a(1:5,:)`

> In Numpy :
> `a[0:5] or a[:5] or a[0:5,:]`

Check out :  [Numpy for Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

if you do not want to use Numpy, try the comprehension lists :

`Year_Data = [ [datmat.data(i,j) for j in range (4,38) ] for i in range(j,j+2) ]`

**EDIT:**

```
for i in range(runs) :
    datamat = numpy.genfromtxt('data.txt',delimiter=' ', newline ='\n' ) 
    // Adapt the previous line to the format of your txt file
    // at this point you should have a numpy.array object with the right shape
    Limits_Area= numpy.array( [1,261,522,784,1045,1305,1565,1827,2088,2349,2610,2871,3131,3158] )
    for k in range(2000):
        for j in range(13):
            Year_Data = datmat[ Limits_Area(j):Limits_Area(j+1)-1 , 4:37 ]
            etc etc ...
```

NB : Matlab arrays indexes goes from 1 to n whereas numpy arrays indexes goes from 0 to n-1

Comment: I wouldn't make an attempt to port any serious matlab code to python without numpy.

Comment: yes I use numpy, so what does this specific line does in Matlab and how would it translate to python? thanks this seems like it's on the right track.

Comment: Also worth a look at the [Online Matlab to Python Converter](http://ompc.juricap.com/). The project appears to be inactive, which is a pity, but there may be something to download that can help. However, I second mgilson's comment. Use NumPy for this.